# jacoco coverage of JUnits in Linux OS

Tags: linux, code-coverage, jacoco

I can able to use this Jacoco coverage in Windows machine. I want to know whether this works for Linux machine or not. If it works, tell me how. If it doesn't, please tell me the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Jacoco is implemented in Java and usually ran from Maven or Ant or Jenkins, which are also implemented in Java. Java works on both Windows and Linux, so there should not be any issue with running Jacoco in Linux.

You could have issues with running your build, say under Maven, if your pom file definition contains Windows specific paths and settings. This would cause your build process to break, not the Jacoco run. If you manage to have a successful build in Linux then it should easy to get Jacoco to run as well.